# web scrape all items in a page with selenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to bring all items in the webpage-for instance I would like to bring the first

"Hillebrand Boudewynsz. van der Aa (1661 - 1717)"
and then all the other 49 in the page
MY code is below, I am trying to use selenium and bring the items through xpath or CSS
but I am not sure for the right path
both options will be welcome
this is the required sentence from the code
#Finding element
object<-remDr$findElement(using="xpath","/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
and the website
https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/index.php?subtask=browse

```
rm(list=ls())
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("robotstxt")
library( robotstxt)
#install.packages("RSelenium")
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("netstat")
library(netstat)
library(wdman)
selenium()

# see path
selenium_object<-selenium(retcommand = T,check = F)

#binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

#start the server
remote_driver<-rsDriver(
  
  browser = "chrome",
  
  chromever = "113.0.5672.63",
  verbose = F,
  port = free_port()
)

# create a client object
remDr<-remote_driver$client

#open a browser
remDr$open()

# maximaize window size
remDr$maxWindowSize()

#navigate website
remDr$navigate("https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/index.php?subtask=browse")

#Finding element
object<-remDr$findElement(using="xpath","/html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSelenium / Selenium should be your last resort when scraping websites. This site can easily be scraped with `rvest` in R. This is how you can scrape **all** links from its 26 pages, saved in a tibble / data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

scraper <- function(page) {
  cat("Scraping page", page, "\n")
  str_c("https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/index.php?subtask=browse&field=surname&strtchar=A&page=", page) %>%  
    read_html() %>% 
    html_elements("ul") %>% 
    pluck(2) %>% 
    html_elements("a") %>% 
    map_dfr(., ~ tibble(
      name = .x %>% 
        html_text2(), 
      link = .x %>% 
        html_attr("href") %>% 
        str_replace("..", "https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico")
    )) %>% 
    mutate(page = page)
}

df <- map_dfr(1:26, scraper)

# A tibble: 1,269 × 3
   name                                            link                                                         page
   <chr>                                           <chr>                                                       <int>
 1 Hillebrand Boudewynsz. van der Aa (1661 - 1717) https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/414       1
 2 Boudewijn Pietersz van der Aa (? - ?)           https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/10566     1
 3 Pieter Boudewijnsz. van der Aa (1659 - 1733)    https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/10567     1
 4 Boudewyn van der Aa (1672 - ca. 1714)           https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/10568     1
 5 Machtelt van der Aa (? - ?)                     https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/27132     1
 6 Claas van der Aa I (? - ?)                      https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/33780     1
 7 Claas van der Aa II (? - ?)                     https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/33781     1
 8 Willem van der Aa (? - ?)                       https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/33782     1
 9 Johanna van der Aa (? - ?)                      https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/59894     1
10 Hans von Aachen (1552 - 1615)                   https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/9203      1
# ℹ 1,259 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work for you!

```html
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.vondel.humanities.uva.nl/ecartico/persons/index.php?subtask=browse"
all_data = []

# Selenium Configuration
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Running in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    # Access to page
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for products to load
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#setwidth > ul > li > a")))

    # Get the HTML content of the page
    html = driver.page_source
finally:
    driver.quit()  # Close the browser even if an exception occurs

# Extracting the necessary data using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
products = soup.select('#setwidth > ul > li > a')

for title in products:
    title_text = title.get_text(strip=True) if title else ""
    all_data.append([title_text])

# Write data to a CSV file
with open("vondel.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['Title'])
    writer.writerows(all_data)
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, this is very good, very helpful , I would like enhance my r skills, does anyone know in addition, how to perform it with R through "xpath" or css